# sql exception, missing parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I'm trying to write some values to my SQL through the C# WinForm I'm building. I'm getting an error I can't resolve.

I am calling this:

```
SQL.insertIntoChildTable(Convert.ToInt32(child_IDTextBox.Text), 
                         child_FirstNameTextBox.Text, 
                         child_LastNameTextBox.Text, 
                         Convert.ToInt32(parent1IDTextBox.Text), 
                         Convert.ToInt32(parent2IDTextBox.Text), 
                         birthdayDateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString(), 
                         age.ToString(), 
                         null, null, null, null, null, 
                         child_disciplineTextBox.Text, child_NotesTextBox.Text);
```

From this:

```
public static void insertIntoChildTable(int childID, string firstName, string lastName, int parent1ID, int parent2ID, string birthdate, string age, string lastCheckedInTime, string lastCheckedInBy, string lastCheckOutTime, string lastCheckedOutBy, string ageGroup, string disciplineNotes, string otherNotes)
{
   try
   {
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString))
       using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
       {
          command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProjectList (ChildID, FirstName, LastName, Parent1ID, Parent2ID, Birthdate, Age, LastCheckedInTime, LastCheckedInBy, LastCheckOutTime, LastCheckedOutBy, AgeGroup, DisciplineNotes, OtherNotes) VALUES (@childID, @firstName, @lastName, @parent1ID, @parent2ID, @birthdate, @age, @lastCheckedInTime, @lastCheckedInBy, @lastCheckOutTime, @lastCheckedOutBy, @ageGroup, @disciplineNotes, @otherNotes)";

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", childID);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parent1ID", parent1ID);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parent2ID", parent2ID);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdate);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckedInTime", lastCheckedInTime);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckedInBy", lastCheckedInBy);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckOutTime", lastCheckOutTime);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckedOutBy", lastCheckedOutBy);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ageGroup", ageGroup);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disciplineNotes", disciplineNotes);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherNotes", otherNotes);

          connection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And getting this:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   The parameterized query '(@childID int,@firstName nvarchar(4),@lastName nvarchar(5),@pare' expects the parameter
>   '@lastCheckedInTime', which was not supplied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Think you want to specify the command.CommandType = CommandType.Text to be explicit (not necessarily the cause of the problem but good practice).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing it is `null`. Parameters that are `null` are not added. It needs to be `DBNull.Value`. You can do this by adding `?? DBNull.Value` to each parameter. Stupid, I know:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastCheckInTime",
      lastCheckInTime ?? DBNull.Value);
```

for **every** parameter; or loop over them afterwards, fixing any `null` to `DBNull.Value`:

```
foreach(var param in command.Parameters) {
    if(param.Value == null) param.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

As a side thing - having those all as `string` sounds very unlikely; should be `DateTime` or `DateTime?`, no?

Comment: yup `null` works different in SQL. thanks. and i'm converting everything to text because I'm just trying to get this thing up and running. Casting the values to the correct type WILL come, I just need more experience. thanks again.